# Should a null block be used for semantic purposes?

Tags: optimization, patterns-and-practices, noop

I was writing a procedure that is only applicable in a particular case, but it didn't feel right to enforce it by contract or raising exceptions, because there's no problem with calling it in other contexts; it just shouldn't do anything.

Thinking about it, I decided it would be easier for future debugging if I explicitly pointed out that the procedure should do nothing. I could have added a comment to that effect, but since I was already explicitly wrapping the body in an if statement, it was just as easy to add a null elsif as in the following (Ada-like) pseudocode:

```
if A then
    --do stuff
elsif B then
    null;
end if;
```

This is logically equivalent to:

```
if A then
    --do stuff
end if;
```

I'm guessing most modern compilers' optimize step will even generate identical binaries for the two above excerpts. Perhaps unoptimized, there would be an extra branch and noop.

So the question is, are null blocks that exist for semantic purposes only, that will almost certainly be optimized out, considered bad practice, or is it a good idea to leave them in as a debugging aid that explicitly points out that nothing should happen in the (ir)relevant case?

Comment: I don't get the `B` part and the lack of an ultimate `else null;` clause — I guess I would add an ultimate else, or maybe better change the `elif` into an `else` eliminating `B`.  Otherwise, I'd say your code commenting of "do nothing in this case" is appropriate, as is another code comment saying that `null;` is a place to put a break point to stop when that case is hit.

Comment: What Erik says - your fragments are _not_ logically equivalent unless B = ¬A, and in that case your code is deliberately obtuse because you should just write ¬A.

Comment: A lot of static code analysis tools are typically configured to raise warnings for anything which might be considered 'redundant' code -- so by this measure it's almost certainly a code smell.   (Because leaving anything which your code analysis tools are warning about is generally bad -- these should either be fixed or suppressed with a comment explaining why it isn't fixed.)

Comment: @PhilipKendall actually they are logically equivalent, until you replace null with something. Which just re-enforces how completely confusing this code is. The B could be anything and the behavior is the same. Which makes the B distracting.

Answer (score 3):

Quietly doing nothing is not a code smell.

Only sometimes quietly doing nothing is not a code smell.

But saying this:

```
if A then
    --do stuff
elsif B then
    null;
end if;
```

is logically equivalent to:

```
if A then
    --do stuff
end if;
```

is just annoying. Sure, the two listings will do the exact same *nothing* in the exact same cases. But that completely ignores the effect this code has on humans reading it.

The first listing makes the `B` case *nothing* explicit. That’s not a small thing. It could easily be a pointless annoying thing. I actually hate seeing empty else cases for no good reason.

So yes, the logical behavior is the same. But you’d better have a damn good reason to be distracting me with a this `B`. Because in its current form the code doesn’t actually care about it. Why are you making me?

As for pointing out that a method may do nothing, that is always true. Go study the Null Object Pattern for a lesson on that.

Doing nothing quietly is only bad when something has gone wrong that should be reported. Sometimes doing nothing quietly is exactly the right thing to do.

People are funny about nothing. It bothers them even in cases where it’s fine.  Learn the value of nothing. It can be nice to have.

Answer (score 3):

This depends somewhat on the language you are using and the conventions that are expected but I would not use this approach if your goal is "that the procedure should do nothing" when A is not true.

The problem with this:

```
if A then
    --do stuff
elsif B then
    null;
end if;
```

Is that it's easy to mistakenly add behavior after the if clause that will execute in either case.  That's not an issue if you need that but if you really want to 'do nothing' in the case of `NOT A`, I very much prefer a guard clause:

```
if not A then
   return;

-- do stuff
```

Comment: +1 Guards express intent very well.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think its great to add an else that does nothing, but I do think you have a point. A function that only works if a condition is hit at the start is a bit of a code smell.

I think the fix is not to add an empty else but to either throw an exception in a guard clause, or refactor to return something. ie.

```
DoSomething()
{
   if(!x) { throw("not x") } //do the check before you call!
   //Do Something
}

result DoMetaSomething(input)
{
   if(!x) 
   { 
     result = //the result of not doing the thing       
   }
   else
   {
     result = //the result of doing something 
   }
   return result
}
```

Of course there must be many cases where you do want to not do anything for performance, say `Sort()` when its already sorted, there's no point crying about code readability when its clearly better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this pattern is that it is not extensible. Imagine another programmer comes along and wants to add a second condition. What is he doing to write?

```
if A then
    if B then
        --do stuff
    else
        null
    else
else
    null
end if
```

You can imagine what it would look like with three conditions! It just becomes an annoying chore to maintain.

Instead, I recommend using a [guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)):

```
if not A then return;
if not B then return;
--do stuff
```

This makes it clear that the function does nothing under certain conditions, and it is easy to add more conditions without disturbing the body of the code.

It also avoids the [arrow](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) anti-pattern.